# Projection from a parabolic sugroup to its Levi component in $GL_n$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $G=GL_n$ and $P_J = B W_J B$ a parabolic subgroup of $G$, $J \subset I$, $I=\{1，2，\cdots, n-1\}$.

Let $P_J = U L$ be the Levi decomposition, where $L$ is the Levi subgroup of $I_J$ and $U$ the unipotent radical.

Let $\pi_J: P_J \to L = P_J/U$ be the natural projection. I am trying to under this projection.

Let 
$$
g = 
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & x_{1,3} & x_{1,4} & x_{1,5}\\ 0 & x_{2,2} & x_{2,3} & x_{2,4} & x_{2,5}\\ 0& x_{3,2} & x_{3,3} & x_{3,4} & x_{3,5}\\ 0& x_{4,2} & x_{4,3} & x_{4,4} & x_{4,5}\\ 0& 0 & 0& 0& x_{5,5} \end{array}\right) \in P_J,
$$
and $J=\{2,3,4\}$.

Do we have $\pi_J(g)=a U$, where
\begin{align}
a=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} x_{1,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & x_{2,2} & x_{2,3} & x_{2,4} & 0\\ 0 & x_{3,2} & x_{3,3} & x_{3,4} & 0\\ 0 & x_{4,2} & x_{4,3} & x_{4,4} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_{5,5} \end{array}\right)?
\end{align}

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your $g$ should be in the parabolic (and by the way, you did not specify which parabolic you consider).

Comment: @Sasha, thank you very much. Yes, $g \in P_J$.

Comment: You still did not specify which parabolic. Persumably the one given by $\{2,3,4\}$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, yes, $J=\{2,3,4\}$.

Comment: @LJR: Then in your formula for $g$ you should write $0$ instead of $x_{i,1}$, $i \ge 2$ and $x_{5,j}$, $j \le 4$.

Comment: @Sasha, thank you. I have edited the text.

Comment: @LJR: Now the answer to your question is "yes".